# Why are there two different Firefox icons?

Tags: notification-icons, firefox-for-android

[image]

Why are there two different Firefox icons? The version is 57 I guess.

Comment: Pull the notification bar down to see why. Maybe it's a notification

Comment: I'm so forgetful that after *screenshoting* it I forgot to see why...

Comment: I mean, I need it to happen again, but I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single app can use **different** `small-icons` or `status-bar-icons` for different notifications. 
In your case there are two notifications from Firefox for which the icons are different.
[image: Like this] [image: Actual notifications from Firefox]

They are set programmatically like `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_name)` for every notification.

Comment: What are the differences between `small-icons` and `status-bar-icons`?

Comment: they are same, programmatically `smallIcon` is used. `status-bar-icon` is common term.

Comment: ah, you should put the plural *s* outside the markdown. Anyway, I wonder why they need to use different icons...

Comment: there must be some logic in developers mind, who knows